# How to optimize a regex with PCREGrep to avoid hitting resource limits

Tags: shell, pcregrep

I'm trying to grep for suppressions containing a certain library in a Valgrind log which is a couple of million lines long with PCREGrep.

I can get each suppression individually using `pcregrep -M "{\n([^}]+\n)+}"` which produces individual entries like this:

```
{
   <insert_a_suppression_name_here>
   Memcheck:ReallocZero
   fun:realloc
   obj:/usr/lib/libnvidia-glcore.so.535.54.03
   obj:/usr/lib/libGLX_nvidia.so.535.54.03
   obj:/usr/lib/libGLX_nvidia.so.535.54.03
   obj:/usr/lib/libGLX_nvidia.so.535.54.03
}
```

What I wanted to do was find all entries which reference `nvidia`, so I tried `{\n([^}]+\n)+.+nvidia.+\n([^}]+\n)+}`. This causes PCREGrep to produce output which looks like this:

```
pcregrep: pcre_exec() gave error -8 while matching text that starts:

{
   <insert_a_suppression_name_here>
   Memcheck:Value8
   obj:/usr/lib/libnvidia-glcore.so.535.54.03
   obj:/usr/lib/libnvidia-glcore.so.535.54.03
   obj:/usr/lib/libnvidia-glcore.so.535.54.03
   ob
```

as well as the terminating message

```
pcregrep: Too many errors - abandoned.
pcregrep: Error -8, -21 or -27 means that a resource limit was exceeded.
pcregrep: Check your regex for nested unlimited loops.
```

How can I format this regex in a way that doesn't cause this issue? Or if the issue is inherently present in my scenario, how can I increase whatever limit is being hit?

Comment: Try a pattern of `\{[^}]+?nvidia[^}]+?\}`, which should need much much much less backtracking.

Comment: Nested +'s like you were using give exponential behavior. I suggest the book [Mastering Regular Expressions](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/mastering-regular-expressions/0596528124/)

Comment: (`\{(?:nvidia|[^}])+?\}` might be even better)